# Swift fetch images and videos from camera roll

Tags: swift, phasset

I am using "PHAsset" for fetching camera roll assets. I am using

```
PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(.Image, options: options)
```

for fetching all gallery images. But I want to fetch all Images and Videos at a same time and show in a collection view (like Instagram camera view).

Can any one please tell me how can I do it?

Comment: improved formatting

Answer (score 17):

Actual Solution (swift 4 and probably swift 3):
In your viewDidLoad or where ever is right for your case call checkAuthorizationForPhotoLibraryAndGet()

```
    private func getPhotosAndVideos(){

        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate",ascending: false)]
        fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d || mediaType = %d", PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue, PHAssetMediaType.video.rawValue)
        let imagesAndVideos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: fetchOptions)
        print(imagesAndVideos.count)
    }

    private func checkAuthorizationForPhotoLibraryAndGet(){
        let status = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()

        if (status == PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
            // Access has been granted.
            getPhotosAndVideos()
        }else {
            PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ (newStatus) in

                if (newStatus == PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
                        self.getPhotosAndVideos()
                }else {

                }
            })
        }
    }
```

1) Make sure mediaType = %d  is used instead of mediaType == %d

2) Make sure you actually have authorization and can access the photo library, otherwise it would fail silently.

Comment: 1) Make sure mediaType = %d is used instead of mediaType == %d
what is the meaning of this iline.

Answer (score 5):

Fell free to use `NSPredicate`.

```
let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", 
                                                 ascending: false)]
fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType == %d || mediaType == %d", 
                                     PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue,
                                     PHAssetMediaType.video.rawValue)
fetchOptions.fetchLimit = 100

let imagesAndVideos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: fetchOptions)
```

Comment: Thanks, can I know how to play that video if I click on UICollectionViewCell?

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you:

```
let allMedia = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithOptions(fetchOptions)
let allPhotos = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(.Image, options: fetchOptions)
let allVideo = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(.Video, options: fetchOptions)
print("Found \(allMedia.count) media")
print("Found \(allPhotos.count) images")
print("Found \(allVideo.count) videos")
```

The Media types are defined as:

```
public enum PHAssetMediaType : Int {

    case Unknown
    case Image
    case Video
    case Audio
}
```

Because it's not an `OptionSetType` you can't use it like a bitfield and combine them for  `PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType`, but the `PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithOptions` might work for you.  Just be prepared to filter out Audio types from the result set.